# Cannot login to SharePoint online with SharePoint Search Query Tool

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I'm using the open source SharePoint Search Query tool (https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) to debug SharePoint Search REST API Queries.

This works fine for on premise, but not for SharePoint Online.

We are using corporate accounts (ADFS?) to login to SharePoint online. I'm connecting from our tenant from outside of our corporate network (public internet) and using the web login.

I can select 'Authentication: Authenticate using specific user account' and 'Authentication Method: SharePoint Online' and then click on the button 'Sign-in to SP Online'

[image: settings and login screen]

After entering my login name for our tenant a redirect screen flashes by (so far so good):

[image: redirect screen]

But finally I'm redirected to an empty page and I'm stuck:

[image: Empty page]

How could I solve this?

Are there any workarounds to get it working? Is there an alternative tool which offers the same functionality?

Comment: It's already logged as a known bug when using the tool with ADFS https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/workitem/1817

Comment: that's not exactly the same issue, as I'm connecting from outside of the corporate network and just using the web login. I'll update the question with that information. According to the workitem my scenario should work, but for me it doesn't.

Comment: "I have the same issue, but it does happen when connecting from outside the corporate network." First comment on that work item, which matches your issue?  Also, voting to close, as this is a third party plugin.

Comment: you are right about the comment on the work item. About it being a third party plugin: afaik this tool is widely used in the community to debug REST Search Queries and that there is no Microsoft alternative. But I'll rephrase the question to indicate that it's not specifically about the tool, but about the ability to debug REST Search queries with any tool.